# how to solve hide and visible issue by jquery

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

I'm trying to make a scenario. At each row, there is two button(One is "Add Me" and another is: "Modify Me") and a text-link("Select"). I want that, By default, "Add Me" button is hidden. if anyone click "Select", "Select" should be changed to "Deselect" and "Modify Me" button should be disappeared and "Add Me" button should be visible. If anyone click on the "Deselect", opposite event should be happened.

I've made the "Select" text to "Deslect". But, "Add Me" button hasn't come. Besides this, changing from "Deselct" to "Select" and visible of "Modify Me" button instead of "Add Me" button is not working.

This is my work: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/hyNT3/

```
$(".selected").click(function(){

  $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('deselected').text('Deselct');
    $(this).next(".addBtn").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(this).next(".modifyBtn").hide();
});

$(".deselected").click(function(){

                    $(this).find('deselected').removeClass('deselected').addClass('selected').text('Select');
    $(this).next(".addBtn").hide();
    $(this).next(".modifyBtn").show();
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(".addbtn").hide();
$(document).on('click', '.right', function(e) {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Select' ? 'Deselect' : 'Select');
    $(this).parent().find('.addbtn, .modifyBtn').toggle();
});
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/hyNT3/1/

Comment: Thanks. At your fiddle it's working. But, unfortunately, at my exact code, it's not working. Can you please take a glance and tell me how to make those two button working at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/J6c3z/2/

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as my accepted answer as it's solved the requirement of the question. But, I don't know why, it's not working at my given link at previous comment. Can you please help me for solving that?

Comment: try changing the selector for .addbtn to siblings() or prev().

Comment: thank you so much! It's working by using prev()
http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/J6c3z/3/

Comment: Explain your answer, this isn't a code sharing website.